# Asp.NET Core 2.1 HostedService - keep running on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

We have a web application that is using the IHostedService.
There is an example of this [here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/a7dd5064d9dcf35b6eae1a7953d615e3)

And the method we employed is detailed [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice)

The goal was to have an application that continually ran background tasks. So we could schedule in jobs that run automatically at set times. This application is separate from all our other applications, so it's not visited by our user base. 
So we needed a way for this application to run all the time on Azure.

We tried to set up an App Service for the application on Azure, but it seems that the application does not continually run. Things seem to run locally ok, but on Azure, I have to stop and restart the service before it kicks in the IHostedService tasks.

Is there a way on Azure to keep the application alive and running?

Comment: You should use a regular VM, docker or kubernetes for that. Azure App Service is hosted in IIS and IIS stops applications when its idle and short on resources. There are plenty of hacks around that (increase idle time on IIS, not sure it works on Azure App Service) or to "ping" the api constantly with a request etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so in the App Settings in Azure, there is a setting `Always On` this worked for us. :)

We also found out from Azure support, that if you are on the lowest tier in their offered packages, this is treated as a "Development" environment and will only have limited up-time. As a result, we could expect the application to go offline when we reached that limit.

We argued that there should have been something more obvious in the dashboard for us to know this.

Once we upgraded to a Standard tier, the application stayed online.

Also, if you are running a hosted service and it hits an unhandled exception, this stops the service. You need to make sure you are handling exceptions for this to work.

Comment: Is that the only change you made? I'm having the same problem, but my app was already set to "Always on"

Comment: That, and we had to upgrade our tier. See my answer.

Comment: It turns out I was being an idiot, and it was being killed by an unhandled exception.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. 
Unhandled exceptions can be identified when you enable Application Insights on an application service and look at the Failures section. There is a good amount of information there including stack traces and the like

Comment: Any idea what tier you have to use?  I have AlwaysOn set to true and am using a production tier S1 and am still seeing behaviour akin to a restart.

Comment: I think we were on S1 in the end for development. Sounds like you need to contact Azure support.